# codegnitor frame work which cannot get a value

Tags: php

Below given the my code its perform a error undefined index `pk_int_stage_id`
in Codeigniter

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT tbl_stage.pk_int_stage_Id FROM tbl_stage JOIN tbl_trip ON tbl_stage.fk_int_route_Id=tbl_trip.fk_int_route_Id WHERE tbl_trip.fk_int_route_Id='7' AND tbl_stage.vchr_stage_starting_point='ne'");


$res=$query->result_array();  
echo $res['pk_int_stage_Id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this:

```
echo $res[0]['pk_int_stage_id'];
```

Comment: first try: print_r($res);

Comment: the data get a in this format      Array ( [0] => Array ( [pk_int_stage_Id] => 4 ) )

Comment: it produce these error          Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Answer (score 0):

you should try:

```
foreach($res as $key=>$value){ 
  echo    $value[0]['pk_int_stage_id'];
}
```

Comment: i have get a answer                foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
        echo $row['pk_int_stage_Id'];
}